# How to completely change tempuri.org namespace in WCF 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, namespaces, wcf-binding

I want to change tempuri.org namespace in my WCF developed in .NET 4.5. All solutions I have found so far addressed the problem in version 4.0 which contains "services" tag in web.config. In case of 4.5, there is no "services" tag so I cannot change binding namespace.

I have found this page: http://blogs.ugidotnet.org/raffaele/archive/2011/02/10/la-soluzione-definitiva-al-namespace-tempuri.org-in-wcf-4.aspx

Which explains how to do that programmatically, but I am wondering if there is any easier solution.

Jaime

Comment: The `<services>` tag still exists in .NET 4.5.  Beginning in .NET 4.0 WCF introduced the concept of simplified configuration, which makes the `<services>` section optional.  You can still use it, though.

Comment: [`<services>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731303(v=vs.110).aspx) - Note that the top of the page says ".NET Framework (current version)".

Answer (score 0):

Just look into your WebServiceName.asmx.cs file and change http://tempuri.org to your own unique string.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace WCFWebService
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class WebServiceName : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
```